# Printing in silverlight 4 with formating

Tags: silverlight-4.0, printing, formatting

Can anyone tell me ow to format the text/document before I send it to print. Below is little explanation of what I am trying to achieve.

I have few lines like below

> To: abcd
>
> From: xyz
>
> Location:blah
>
> Phone:99999999
>
> Sub:something
>
> Message Body:

I can have this all in a `list<string>`; add them to page and print them but the print will not be formatted ... printed outcome will be as above but what I am looking for is kind below:

> To: **abcd**
>
> From: **xyz**
>
> Location: **blah**
>
> Phone: **99999999**

```
                             **Sub   :    something**
```

> Dear abcd,
>
> Some message.
>
> Some other information

any idea how can I achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use Run's inside a textblock like this:

```
<TextBlock>Name: <Run FontWeight="Bold">Hola que tal</Run><LineBreak />
Age: <Run FontWeight="Bold">201</Run><LineBreak /></TextBlock>
```

Comment: Though this is not what I am looking for but your answer helped me to right direction. So, +1.